# Questions about Session variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am currently trying to allow users to "personalize" their background-image on a website I've created with C#-ASP.net. I imagined as far as that I create a if statement, checking if the currently logged in user matches with the session variable created when logging in, and if it does, it allows him to change his/her background-image. Before I did this, I also thought that the best way of testing if it would work that way is to try to write out the content of the session variable directly onto the page. Thats where the issue come in. All I am getting is the "name" of the session variable and nothing else. How can I get this changed?
The code below is pretty much what I've tried with the session variables this far

```
<%
// User with the name of "Bob" is logged in with code further up
var login_username = Request["login_username"];

Session["loggedIn"] = login_username;

Response.Write(Session["loggedIn"]);

// Results in it writing out "loggedIn".
// Expected "Bob".

%>
```

I'm going to be fair, I have no idea if this is enough for anyone to give me a hand and If I am even on the right track, but thats that. If theres a better way of doing this, I'm up for suggestions.

Comment: Are you _certain_ `login_username` is not "loggedIn"?  Can you verify it in the debugger?  Are you passing data through form vars or a URL?

Comment: @DStanley login_username is the *formfield* used when a user enters their name in a login field, "loggedIn" was just the name of the session variable I created.

Comment: Hve you verified that in the debugger?  There's no way that `Session["loggedIn"]` would output `loggedIn` unless _that's what is stored in the session variable_.

Comment: I haven't actually, but since I, which I now know was foolish, wrote Session["loggedIn"] = "loggedIn";, would it make sense for it to write out loggedIn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of logging in, store your username into a session variable,
 for eg:  **Session["loggedIn"] = username**
Then, read the session value to a label text using
 **Convert.ToString(Session["loggedIn"]**

Alternatively, one can write **Response.Write(Session["loggedIn"]);** to get the string of the variable.

Comment: Okay! Will check that as soon as I get the opportunity to! Got the files over at work right now.

Comment: I fixed it by using Response.Write(Session["loggedIn"]); , however, since the first part worked and I'm sure your way would have worked to, I'll mark it as an answer!